# Is lock() type-cast safe?

Tags: c#, locking

```
public class A { }
public class B:A { }

void foo()
{
   A a = new B();
   B b = a as B;
}
```

for a given instance setup, will `lock(a)`  be equivalent to `lock(b)` ?

I mean, will locking be mutually exclusive? If I `lock(a)` in one thread and `lock(b)` in another thread, will I get a mutually exclusive access to that single instance of `B` created earlier?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by equivalent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes `lock(a){}` is equivalent to `lock(b){}`.

[The lock() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.71).aspx) states that the lock statement marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object of reference type.

`a` and `b` are both the same object so yes they are equivalent.   Actually `a` and `b` are both references to the same object.

A cast operation between reference types does not change the run-time type of the underlying object; it only changes the type of the value that is being used as a reference to that object. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

A quick test program shows that it does indeed behave the way it is documented:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class A { }
    public class B : A { }

    class Program
    {
        static A a = new B();

        static void MyThread()
        {
            B b = a as B;
            lock (b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("b lock acquired");
                Console.WriteLine("releasing b lock");
            }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(MyThread);

            lock(a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a lock acquired");               
                t.Start();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("Releasing a lock");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> a lock acquired
>   ... 10 seconds pass
>   releasing a lock
>   b lock acquired
>   releasing b lock